# vimeo You must pass either a valid element or a valid id. at new Player Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, vimeo, vimeo-player

So I have a vimeo player on my page like so...

```
<div class="main" *ngFor="let item of asset">
  <p>{{item.fields.asset[0].fields.textBlock}}</p>
  <div id="video-panel">
    <div [attr.data-vimeo-id]="item.fields.asset[0].fields.vimeoId" data-vimeo-responsive="1" id="video"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now `item.fields.asset[0].fields.vimeoId` is being passed in as the vimeo Id but everytime I try to run the app I get this error

[image]

but If I `console.log` `item.fields.asset[0].fields.vimeoId` I get the correct video Id so in theory it should work...

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Entry } from 'contentful';
import { ContentfulService } from '../../../contentful.service';

declare var Player: any;
declare var Vimeo: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-asset-page',
  templateUrl: './asset-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-page.component.scss']
})
export class AssetPageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  asset: Entry<any>[];
  id: string;
  videoID: string;

  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id')))
    .subscribe((asset) => {
      this.asset = asset;
      console.log(this.asset[0].fields.asset[0].fields.vimeoId);
      const video = new Vimeo.Player('video');
    });
  }
```

Im not sure what Im doing wrong? any help would be appreciated!?

**EDIT**

I can get it to work by doing this..

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.paramMap
.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id')))
.subscribe((asset) => {
  this.asset = asset;
  console.log(this.asset[0].fields.asset[0].fields.vimeoId);
  setTimeout(() => {
    const video = new Vimeo.Player('video');
  }, 500);
});
}
```

but id rather not do something so hacky..

Comment: Try moving the code you have setting the `this.trustedDashboardUrl` right below the line where you set `this.asset = asset;` in the `subscribe`. See if that works.

Comment: @R.Richards I was getting the same issue this.trustedDashboardUrl is undefined, I imagine because the data isnt ready at that time

Comment: Try putting your code inside "ngAfterViewInit" instead of ngOnInit ? On a side note you can optentially have multiple divs with ids 'video-panel' and "video" since it's in a for loop

Comment: @David yeah I tried that but it didnt work, ive stukc with the setTimeout for now